# Can i delete the title bar/caption after the window be created?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi

WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW will got a title bar, how can i delete it after it be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SetWindowLong` with `GWL_STYLE` flag to remove the `WS_OVERLAPPED` flag. Then call `SetWindowPos` with `SWP_FRAMECHANGED` to notify system that the window style has changed